# SharePoint Designer Workflow- Task is saying it's completed when not all participants completed task

Tags: sharepoint-designer

When I assign a Workflow task to multiple people, all users should complete the task before the task is 100% completed, but when the participant who completes the task first, the task automatically goes from In Progress to Completed even though there are multiple users who have not completed their portion of the task yet.

How do I fix this so all users who were assigned the task must click 'Complete' so the task is completed? (not just one user who was assigned the task)

And yes, I started a task process in SharePoint Designer and added multiple emails and selected 'Parallel'as well as set the option to 'Wait for all responses'

Thank you

Comment: Are you using a Task list or is it a standard List which you have customised?

Comment: Hi @Tally, I am using a Task list

Comment: Actually, on SharePoint, it is part of a form library because my workflow is for participants to fill out an infopath form on SharePoint.

Comment: But I'm using a 'task list for workflow'. Sorry for the multiple replies, just a little confusing

Comment: I think I fixed the issue! Well- I think it was a bug because all of a sudden it started working. Thank you

Comment: Hi Samantha, well I'm glad you fixed it!  Perhaps you could post an answer to your question, since I see you've got 3 upvotes for your question plus someone has marked it as a favourite.  This makes me think there is some interest in your question from other users, so they might benefit from your answer. Thanks, Tally

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there was a small bug that fixed itself because this happens quite often for me. But make sure when you are doing this, test the flow with other people's emails **in your organization** and **not your own** email because when I tested it using my own or other emails, it did not work also making me think I had another error/issue arise